# Most efficient way to install Windows Hotfixes on a isolated computer

Tags: windows-update, update, automatic-updates, windows

I have a standalone W2K3 machine which I need to update with microsoft hotfixes. I also have a clone of this machine which I can connect to the internet.

What I'd like to do is:

a) Run some tool on the clone which will download all the required hotfixes from the internet, then I can burn them to a BluRay disk

b) Take that disk to the standalone machine and run an app to install them as required

Does anyone know of a tool to do this. Or alternatively produce the disk in some other way (maybe to include all hotfixes, if this will fit on a BluRay.

Notes:

I'd then install them on the clone using the disk so it's in the same state for the net round of hotfixes.

Currently I use MBSA to run on the standalone machine to see what hotfixes are required, then download them manually, burn them to disk and install them via a script. This works fine, except that downloading them all takes ages

There are also other application updates (e.g. Adobe Reader) which I would like to be able to update with a similar mechanism, although this is a lesser issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WSUS offline update Project (http://www.wsusoffline.net/) allows you to build a repository of MS Updates / Hotfixes for one or more MS OS' and also supplies scripts to deploy them offline from a CD, disk  or internal distribution share.

Comment: Cheers, this is just what I wanted